# Problema al ejecutar en simultaneo reporte jasper ireport

Tags: java, sql-server, ireport, gwt

tengo un proyecto Java GWT, en donde hago una factura, todo el proceso  de guardado y de retorno en la BD SQL funciona bien, el problema es cuando en dos o mas terminales se ejecuta en simultaneo el proceso de venta, ya que al momento de mostrar los datos que irán en las facturas impresas, siempre se muestra solo los datos de una factura en todas las terminales.

Mi reporte se llena con un query directo en el, así que solo espera los 2 parámetros que necesita, eso funciona bien, cuando es solo una terminal o ventas no simultaneas.

Alguien sabe que es lo que puede estar pasando? sera que es problema de mi versión de iReport? alguien a padecido lo mismo?

a la espera de su orientación

Answer (score 0):

A los que les interese o sufran algo parecido, les comento que el proyecto por ser MVC, al momento de solicitar el reporte, lo llamamos desde el lado del cliente, y este desde una clase asincronica nos devolvía el archivo PDF o cualquier otra opción, como pude solucionar es creando un servlet directo solo para ese modulo, a modo de tener una única interacción con el servidor, ya que de la forma inicial hacia 2 llamados al servidor y es allí en donde mostraba solo un paquete de datos en todas las terminales.